# Fill alpaca properties with a variable

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

I need to assemble a form dynamically using Alpaca Forms. I have the code below:

```
$("#form").alpaca({        
    "schema": {            
        "type":"object",
        "properties": {                
            "email": {
                "type":"string",
                "title":"E-mail",
                "required":true
            },
            "mensagem": {
                "type":"string",
                "title":"Mensagem",
                "required":true
            }                                        
        }
    }
});
```

And it needs to be filled in using variables for it to be generic, because the amount of fields that the form will have will always vary. Ex: sometimes in addition to the "email", "mensagem" properties, I will have the "assunto", "remetente", "destinatario" properties

it would need to look something like this:

```
$("#form").alpaca({
    "schema" : { schemaVariable }        
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is possible, you just need to remove the braces from your variable and use proper JSON object declaration.

```
"schema" : schemaVariable
```

here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/ef3uo1wg/) for this.
Tell me if you need something else.